# Continue in executing commands while downloading with Wget [BATCH]

Tags: batch-file

I have this script in my batch file:

```
Wget -q -OUpdate.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip --no-check-certificate & goto next
:next
echo test
```

I want to execute the next commands while Wget is running.

So the output should look like this:

> test

And nothing else. I still want to have the Wget program **working in the background** and **without a second batch file**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `start` command, which has the probably undesirable side effect of creating a new DOS box for the wget command:

```
start Wget -q -OUpdate.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip --no-check-certificate
echo test
```

Actually, you can also use the `/b` option and redirect stdout/stderr to a file or `NUL` to prevent the second DOS box from being created:

```
start /b Wget -q -OUpdate.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip --no-check-certificate >NUL 2>&1
echo test
```

Comment: OMG You're right! I'm so dumb! I knew that there is a simple way that I knew before.. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows environment you can try to create a .CMD file instead of a batch file.

In the cmd file you can use

```
START Wget -q -OUpdate.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9q3ssvhitsatbq/Update.zip --no-check-certificate
```

To start Wget and do not wait for completion, execute the echo Test below and all the lines below.

Wget will run in a separate window.

If you want to execute something at the end of Wget, you can try to combine the waitfor command and send some signal from a batch file that executes just Wget.

http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html here some reference.